# Differential equation and Jordan Canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, jordan-normal-form

This is what my professor wrote:

Let
\begin{equation*}
y_i = y_i(x) ~~~(i = 1, 2, 3)
\end{equation*}
be differentiable functions in $x$. Set
\begin{equation*}
Y =
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
y_3
\end{pmatrix}
, Y^{'} =\begin{pmatrix}
y_{1}^{'}\\
y_{2}^{'}\\
y_{3}^{'}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
We will solve the following differential equations, where $A = (a_{ij})$ is in $M_3(\mathbb{R})$:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
y_{1}^{'}\\
y_{2}^{'}\\
y_{3}^{'}
\end{pmatrix}
= Y^{'} = AY =
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} &a_{12} &a_{13}\\
a_{21} &a_{22} &a_{23}\\
a_{31} &a_{32}& a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
y_3
\end{pmatrix}
,
\end{equation*}
or equivalently
\begin{eqnarray*}
y_{1}^{'}&=& a_{11}y_1 + a_{12}y_2 + a_{13}y_3\\
y_{2}^{'} &= &a_{21}y_1 + a_{22}y_2 + a_{23}y_3\\
y_{3}^{'} &= &a_{31}y_1 + a_{32}y_2 + a_{33}y_3.
\end{eqnarray*}
Let $P$ be an invertible matrix in $M_3(\mathbb{R})$ such that
\begin{equation*}
J := P^{-1} A P
\end{equation*}
is a Jordan canonical form of $A$. etc etc etc...

**My question (could be trivial) is that i thought that the matrix $A$ taken over $\mathbb{R}$ is not guaranteed to have a Jordan canonical form. Or am i missing something?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jordan canonical form of a $3\times 3$ matrix can be a diagonal or not.

If not, there are two cases:

1. There's one block of size 1 with an eigenvalue and a block of size 2 with an eigenvalue in the diagonal and a $1$ in the right upper corner of the block.
2. There's one block of size $1$ with an eigenvalue and a block of size 2 of the form $$\begin{pmatrix}a &b\\ -b & a \end{pmatrix}$$ The coefficients $a,b$ are the real and imaginary parts of the complex eigenvalue. You can read this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices).

It's guaranteed that we have a block of size $1$, because the characteristic polynomial has degree $3$ and a real root.